# Is it possible to install RHEV on el6 clustered computer

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualization, cluster, rhev

Is it possible to use Linux (el6) clustered computer can be used as a hypervisor for RHEV 3.3/Ovirt 3.3?

- Cause, we can not combine RAM/CPU from two or more hypervisores to be considered as a one source of resource while creating a huge guest on RHEV. I know it support Baloonig and 150% for server and 200% for Desktop RAM aloocation  but if I want to allocate RAM even more than that just to a one guest then?

Any input for such situation!

Answer (score 0):

You should NEVER assign a single guest more resources than the hypervisor host it runs on has. Virtualization can allow you to share resources and utilize idle CPU time better, but there is no magic there, it will not provide you with hardware you do not have.